# unsupported operand type(s) for +: int and str in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys just trying to create a function that takes two parameters, n and high, and prints the values of n^1 n^2 up to and including n^high (on a single line) - any help would be great thanks!

```
def print_powers(n, high):
    i = 0
    new = ''
    count = 0
    while i < high:
        count += 1
        while count <= high:
           new += int((n)**count) + ' '
        i += 1
    return new

print(print_powers(2, 5))
```

Comment: You have some answers for your specific question. Also, rather than writing a function to calculate-and-print-powers, I would advise that you write one function to calculate the powers and return a list of values: e.g., `[2, 4, 8, 16, 32]`. Then you can do anything you want with that list of data, including sending it to another function to join them into a space-delimited string and/or printing. In other words, calculation and printing are very different, so keep them separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the integer to a string before appending the space.

```
new += str(int((n)**count)) + ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

`n**count` is an `int` already.  You need to convert it to a `str` before adding it to `' '`. That should say `new += str(n**count) + ' '`.